# Wrong type being used when using simple_form with reform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, reform

Given the following form

```
class EntryForm < Reform::Form
  property :composition
  property :native_language_version

  validates :composition, presence: true
end
```

and the following schema

```
  create_table "entries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "composition"
    t.text     "native_language_version"
    t.integer  "language_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
  end
```

and the following controller code

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @entry = EntryForm.new(Entry.new)
    # @entry = Entry.new
  end
end
```

and the following code for simple_form

```
= simple_form_for(@entry) do |f|
  = f.input :composition
  = f.input :native_language_version
  = f.submit
```

rather than getting a `textarea` for `composition` and `native_language_version`, I get

```
<input class="string required form-control" type="text" name="entry[composition]" id="entry_composition">
```

changing to using `@entry = Entry.new` gives me a textarea element instead, which is what I want:

```
<textarea class="text optional form-control" name="entry[composition]" id="entry_composition"></textarea>
```

I tried adding `type: :text` to the `:composition` property in `EntryForm`, but it didn't help.

I also know that rather than using `f.input` I could specify the actual input type, but that's a hack.

How do I pass the fact that `composition` is a `text` rather than a `string` through `EntryForm` to simple_form?

I'm using Rails 4.2.5.1, simple_form 3.2.1, and reform 2.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. When the model is wrapped by a `Reform::Form`, you have to explicitly tell SimpleForm that you want a textarea.

`= f.input :composition, as: :text_area`

The reason is that when determining column database type SimpleForm [relies on a part of ActiveRecord interface](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/b1da0744ddef55cf323b2e770846df90b61e213b/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L547) which the Reform::Form doesn't provide.